# Change (increase) the size of the arrowhead in \xleftarrow and \xrightarrow inside \begin{array}

Tags: pdftex, arrows, arrays

I need to 'draw' a protocol flow using LaTeX. I decided to go with `\begin{array}`, since it is sufficient for my needs. However, the arrowhead in `\xleftarrow` and `\xrightarrow` is so small, that it is not very readable.

Is there a way to increase its size? Or at least change it to something bigger, which will be easy to see? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c c c}
\text{\textsf{C}} & & \text{\textsf{S}} \\
& \text{\scriptsize \texttt{REQUEST}}  &\\
& \xrightarrow{\hspace{15em}\hspace{10em}} & \\
& \text{\scriptsize \texttt{RESPONSE}} & \\
& \xleftarrow{\hspace{15em}\hspace{10em}} & \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

% add the following two lines to your document to get bigger arrows
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=3mm,length=3mm]}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c c c}
\text{\textsf{C}} & & \text{\textsf{S}} \\
& \text{\scriptsize \texttt{REQUEST}}  &\\
& \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) node[left]{} -- (10,0) node[right]{};
\end{tikzpicture} & \\
& \text{\scriptsize \texttt{RESPONSE}} & \\
& \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<-] (0,0) node[left]{} -- (10,0) node[right]{};
\end{tikzpicture} & \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```